# How to validate 'live' input field with Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Is there a way to validate 'live' input field using Regex in C#? 
'live' means that I don't validate complete string, I want to validate the string while it's typed.
For example, I want my string to match the next pattern lalala111@alalala123, so I have to check each new char - is it @ ? if it's @ then is there a @ already in the string? if yes, then I return a null, if no, then I return the char. And of course I have to check chars - is it letter or digit? if yes, then ok, if not, then not ok.
I hope you got my idea.

At now I have this code

```
private char ValidateEmail(string input, int charIndex, char charToValidate)
    {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(charToValidate) &&
            !(charToValidate >= 'а' && charToValidate <='я') &&
            !(charToValidate >= 'А' && charToValidate <= 'Я') ||
            charToValidate =='@' ||
            "!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@.".Contains(charToValidate.ToString()))
        {
            if ((charToValidate == '@' && input.Contains("@")) ||
                (!input.Contains("@") && charIndex>=63) ||
                (input.Contains("@") && charIndex >= 192))
                return '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            return '\0';
        }

        return char.ToUpper(charToValidate);
    }
```

it allows only latin letters with digits and some special characters, and also it allows first part of the string (before @) to have only 64 letters, and the second part (after @) to have only 128 letters, but the code looks ugly, don't it? So I want to do all these checks in one beauty regular expression.

Comment: you  have to call this function on event onblur() means on client side

Comment: what function? I don't want to use this function, I use it now, but I want to use Regex instead that function

Answer (score 0):

lYou have to use the following code:

Declare this line at top:

```
 System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex remail = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");
```

next either  on button click or leave event pass the following code to check

```
       if (textemail.Text != "" && !remail.IsMatch(textemail.Text))
            {
                errorProvider1.Clear();
                textemail.Focus();
                errorProvider1.SetError(textemail, "Wrong Email ID");
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Email ID");
                textemail.SelectAll();
                return;
            }
```

Comment: no no, I meant how to check it while i'm typing, to prevent adding invalid chars

Answer (score 0):

After a character has been typed, you want the string that has been entered to match one of the following:

- between 1 and 64 (inclusive) acceptablecharacters.
- between 1 and 64 (inclusive) acceptable characters then an `@` character.
- between 1 and 64 (inclusive) acceptable characters then an `@` character then 128 or fewer acceptable characters.

Note that the last two clauses can be combined to say:

- between 1 and 64 (inclusive) acceptable characters then an `@` character then between 0 and 128 inclusive acceptable characters.

Hence the entire requirement can be expressed as:

- between 1 and 64 (inclusive) acceptable characters, optionally followed by an `@` character then between 0 and 128 inclusive acceptable characters.

Where the definition of "acceptable characters" is not at all clear from the question. The code within `ValidateEmail` does range checks of `'a'` to `'я'` and of `'А'` to `'Я'`. It also checks `"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~@.".Contains(...)`.

The text below assumes acceptable characters actually means the 26 letters, upper and lower case, plus the 10 digits.

The required regular expression is then `^\w{1,64}(@\w{0,128})?$`

This regular expression can then be used to check the concatenation of the already validated input text plus the character just typed.

If additional characters are wanted to be considered as acceptable then change the `\w`, there are two of them. For example if underscores (`_`) and hyphens (`-`) are to be allowed then change both `\w`s to be `[\w_-]`.